# How to sign SOAP message in php

Tags: php, web-services, soap, digital-signature, soap-client

I'm using `php` (`yii2`) and I'd like to implement SOAP communication with server. I have following guide to SOAP:

> The Customer’s system uses the Customer’s private key for issuing
>   digital signatures. Both the application request (ApplicationRequest)
>   and the SOAP message must be signed separately in the WSC. The
>   signature is performed with the private key. The signing system must
>   include in the signature also the certificate. This certificate
>   contains the public key  corresponding to the private key used in the
>   signing. The receiver uses the public key to authenticate the
>   signature.

and:

> Next step: Digitally sign (detached type XML Digital Signature) the
>   whole SOAP message with the Private Key of Sender Certificate and put
>   the signature into SOAP-header

So, I have own `private.key`, `public.key` and `certificate.cer`

My code looks like

```
    $client = new SoapClient($wdsl, ['trace' => true]);
    $arguments = ['DownloadFileListRequest' => $dflr];
    $appResponse = $client->__call('downloadFileList', $arguments);
```

But I get the expected error:

`SOAP signature error`

What I have to do and how to sign this SOAP?

Answer (score 1):

`XMLSecurityDSig` helped (https://github.com/robrichards/xmlseclibs)

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$ar = $dom->createElementNS('http://bxd.fi/xmldata/', 'ApplicationRequest');
$dom->appendChild($ar);
$ar->appendChild($dom->createElement('CustomerId', $this->userID));
...
$ar->appendChild($dom->createElement('Content', $contentBase64));

$objDSig = new XMLSecurityDSig();
$objDSig->setCanonicalMethod(XMLSecurityDSig::EXC_C14N);
$objDSig->addReference(
            $dom,
            XMLSecurityDSig::SHA256,
            ['http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature'],
            ['force_uri' => true]
        );
$objKey = new XMLSecurityKey(XMLSecurityKey::RSA_SHA256, ['type'=>'private']);
$objKey->loadKey($this->privateKeyPath, true);
$objDSig->sign($objKey);
$objDSig->add509Cert(base64_encode(file_get_contents($this->certificatePath)), false);
$objDSig->appendSignature($dom->documentElement);

$xmlRaw = $dom->saveXML();
```